# Firebase: How to re-authenticate custom authenticated users?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have successfully implemented custom authentication system (not email and password normal authentication) as shown in the docs in my backend:

Server side:

```
authAdmin.auth().createCustomToken(uid)
 .then(customToken => {
   response.send({token: customToken});
}).catch(error => {
  console.log(error)
  response.status(500).send(error);
});
```

Client side:

```
let token = response.json().token;
firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(response.token).then(user => {
   // Code
}).catch(function(error) {
   console.log(error)
});
```

Now I need to delete the created account and since the account needs to be freshly authenticated to be deleted otherwise it has to be re-authenticated.
I checked the docs and I found this:

```
currentUser.reauthenticateAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(credential).then(() => {
  // Delete user
  currentUser.delete().then(() => {
    // User deleted 
  });
});
```

But this function takes a credential object. So the question is how to make a credential object out of the custom authentication system provided above ?

Comment: Negative. This question asks about re-authenticating email and password authenticated users. I do custom authentication.

Comment: Yep, my mistake. So you can't use any of these classes - https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth#classes?

Comment: Cannot see any other way to create a credential object other than using the well known providers such as Facebook and so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK here is how you do it. You need another FirebaseApp.

```
var app2 = firebase.initializeApp(sameConfig, 'temp');
app2.auth().signInWithCustomToken(token).then(function(result) {
  // Confirm this is the same user as the default app.
  if (firebase.auth().currentUser.uid == result.user.uid) {
    // Overwrite the user in default instance.
    return firebase.auth().updateCurrentUser(result.user);
  }
  throw new Error('User mismatch!');
}).then(function() {
  // User reauthenticated. Remove temp user.
  app2.auth().signOut();
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Error occurred.
});
```

Comment: Smart approach. So you are basically re-signing the user in from another app, then updating the originally signed user in the main app instance, and finally sign the temp user out. Very clever !. One question, signing a user from another app instance won't affect the authentication listeners because they are created from the main app auth instance right ?

Comment: The `authStateListeners` for app2 will trigger when `app2.auth().signInWithCustomToken` is called. When `updateCurrentUser` is called, `authStateListeners`  for default app will not trigger since the same user is signed in. You can test it. Try signInWithCustomToken twice. Only the first time triggers. If the same user signs in multiple times without signing out, no state change is triggered.